# Passing more than one parameter from jQuery to ASHX

Tags: jquery, ashx

How can I pass more than one parameter from jQuery to an ASHX file. I want to send three values with [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29), not [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
 'type' : 'POST',
 'url' : '/my_great_ashx_file.ashx',
 'data' : {
  'first_field' : 'foo',
  'second_field' : 'bar',
  'third_field' : 'buz'
 },
 'success' : function () {
  alert('This was a triumph.');
 }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```

Code from: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/